# org.apache.parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException: A group type can not be empty. Parquet does not support empty group without leaves

Tags: java, avro, parquet

I am trying to write some record into parquet file in java.

Following is my sample code:

```
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE;
import static org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path dataFile = new Path("/tmp/UpdateMetaData.snappy.parquet");

        try {
            ParquetWriter<UpdateMeta> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<UpdateMeta>builder(dataFile)
                    .withSchema(ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(UpdateMeta.class))
                    .withDataModel(ReflectData.get())
                    .withConf(new Configuration())
                    .withCompressionCodec(SNAPPY)
                    .withWriteMode(OVERWRITE)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class UpdateMeta {
    String updatedBy;
    Date updatedAt;
    Set<EmailContentField> emailContentField;
}
```

But I am getting following exception:

> org.apache.parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException: A group type can not
>   be empty. Parquet does not support empty group without leaves. Empty
>   group: updatedAt  at
>   org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.(GroupType.java:92)     at
>   org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.(GroupType.java:48)     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertUnion(AvroSchemaConverter.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertField(AvroSchemaConverter.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convertFields(AvroSchemaConverter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.writeSupport(AvroParquetWriter.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter.access$100(AvroParquetWriter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter$Builder.getWriteSupport(AvroParquetWriter.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:489)
>     at com.gartner.emailactivityimporter.dao.App.main(App.java:26)

Following are the dependencies I am using in my my pom file:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-avro -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
    <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help me to solve this exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can't write `Date/Timestamp` to parquet directly with above version of dependency.

So either we need to convert `Date/Timestamp` to `String` or `long`. And it worked.

Please comment if you have any other solution or suggestion.

Thanks